# Three.js - Stencil only on certain objects

Tags: three.js, stencil-buffer

I'm looking into making kind of a portal effect using Three.js.

The main idea is to be able to see through multiple windows another Scene.

Exactly like in this example :
https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/post/022-stencil-buffers/ (See gif in article, too big to upload here)

I found an exact example of what i'm trying to do using three.js.

Here is the link :
https://sites.google.com/site/cgwith3js/home/masking-with-stencil

The fiddle was not working but I changed it to make it work :
http://jsfiddle.net/yzhreu6p/23/

```
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  sceneStencil = new THREE.Scene();
...
  scene.add(box); // red one
...
  function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.clear();
    
  // animate the box
  box.position.x = Math.cos(clock.getElapsedTime()) * 10;

  var gl = renderer.getContext();

  // enable stencil test
  gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  //renderer.state.setStencilTest( true );

  // config the stencil buffer to collect data for testing
  gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xff);
  gl.stencilOp(gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE);

    // render shape for stencil test
  renderer.render(sceneStencil, camera);
  
  // set stencil buffer for testing
  gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xff);
  gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP);

  // render actual scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // disable stencil test
  gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  }
```

Then I reuse the code in my project where I have kind of a town with buildings, and the hidden scene has a nyan cat textured box.

The problem I'm having is that the planes are disappearing when a building is behind and more serious problem, when there are buildings back the nyan cat texture, we see the texture in the building.

To better explain here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DpLW.png)

I'm looking for a solution where the images are not visible inside the building, I found people that are talking about stencilMask but it's new for me.

Do I need to create another scene to make it work independently ?

If someone can help me, thank you for reading.

Comment: Do not include the WebGL tag with the three.js tag.

Comment: @Rojo in this case I believe the `webgl` tag is warranted, since Anat is performing raw WebGLContext API calls on top of Three.js when making stencil tests, such as `gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xff);`